# Changing Google Forms question options without affecting existing answers

Tags: google-forms, google-workspace

I have a Google Forms questionnaire which has already received a number of answers. I've noticed that many of the questions are "checkboxes" when they should've been "multiple choice" questions. If I correct that now, what impact (if any) will it have on the already recorded answers? I.e. will it corrupt the recorded answers somehow, or is it safe to go ahead with changing the checkbox questions to multiple choice questions?

Comment: Brian, I am reluctant to take responsibility for what might be a costly error however... my testing shows that if a question type is changed from `checkboxes` to `Multiple choice`, the existing submissions are unaffected. You should be able to confirm this by your own testing. On a tangent, `Checkboxes` questions allow **one or more options** to be selected vs `Multiple Choice` questions allow **one option only** to be selected. So how one would interpret existing submissions that have multiple selections (via "checkboxes") is an issue to be considered.

Comment: Sorry, Joel, I just realised that I directed my comment to Brian instead of you.